# Bring split task from Microsoft Project to dhtmlxgantt

Tags: javascript

I use javascript, I would like to bring “update project” function in Microsoft Project to be used in dhtmlxgantt. I wonder how to bring “split task” data into dhtmlxgantt? I don’t know how to split task in dhtmlxgantt. Please suggest, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to bring “update project” function in Microsoft Project to be used in dhtmlxgantt.

You need to use the Gantt API to implement a custom solution.

To iterate tasks, you need to use the `eachTask` method:

https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/api__gantt_eachtask.html

There, you can compare the task's `start_date` with the target date. If it is lower that the target date, you calculate the proportion: (target date - start_date) / (end_date - start_date). And this will be the `progress` value.

To repaint the changes, you need to use the `refreshTask` or `updateTask` method:

https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/api__gantt_updatetask.html

To repaint the changes only once for all tasks, you need to put the code inside the `batchUpdate` method:

https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/api__gantt_batchupdate.html

Here is an example of how it can be implemented:

https://snippet.dhtmlx.com/nl413dnz

---

> I wonder how to bring “split task” data into dhtmlxgantt? I don’t know how to split task in dhtmlxgantt.

To display several tasks on the same row, you need to add the `render: "split"` property to the parent task, then its children will be displayed on the same row:

https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/desktop__split_tasks.html

Here are the samples:

https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/samples/04_customization/11_split_task.html
https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/samples/04_customization/21_open_split_task.html